# Dynamic Layout Manager to arrange images

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, image, layout

I need to display a set of images as rows and columns in a form. The layout should be user selectable similar to MS Word 2007+ - Table Insert functionality ie. rows & columns need to generated during runtime. Is there a built-in layout manager to support this functionality?

Thanks,

John

Comment: You haven't described the *functionality* with enough details.

Comment: The OP looks like Hit and Run he hadn't visited the site after asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zah8ywcc.aspx) to do similar to what you want.

If you want Proper control of Rows and Columns then you can use [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx)

In both Container controls you can add Subcontrols (Picture boxes in your case) at runtime and In Table Layout Panel you can set [RowCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.rowcount.aspx) and [ColumnCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.columncount.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, the FlowLayoutPanel serves my requirement well. A related question: If you have noticed, in Word 2007, Insert Table allows the user to choose rows/columns from a grid of small boxes rather than type in values for rows/columns. How can i achieve the same functionality?

Comment: well you will need to do a little bit of coding..here is a logic.. have a Control(Panel maybe) fill it with some row and columns like a 8x8 grid(like in word).. then in MouseOver Event just check the user's mouse x,y position and select boxes covered from origin to the mouse position and.... you have row and columns count